# I am trying to write a program to inform of how long it takes to count to a googol in python

Tags: python, time, count

I am attempting to write a program that keeps track of the time to count to a googol, that is ten to the power of 100. The way I am doing it is so the person counts, "one, zero", for 10, etc... so it's easier. This is the code I am using,

```
 from math import *

x = 10
y = 100
num = 0
up = 1
counter = 0
upper = 9
googol = pow(x, y)


while googol > 0:
    num += up
    counter += 1
    googol -= 1
    if counter == upper:
        up += 1
        upper *= 10 + 9
 print num
```

This is hard to run because it takes so long, is this worth leaving to run for a while or will it be a time too long to ever get an answer? Do you know any alternatives for code or languages?

Comment: Make your program count to one million or one billion, then multiply that time to extrapolate for a googl to see if it's worth waiting for or not.

Comment: And remember that adding larger integers may take longer than small integers. The above estimate gives a good lower bound only.

Comment: You need a super computer for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can never do this on a desktop computer. Say that you can do 3 billion iterations a second (which is a *big* overestimate for most or all desktop computers). Even at that speed you would need about [10^83 *years*](https://www.google.se/search?q=googol%20/%203GHz%20in%20years)!

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just needed a second opinion, thanks.